# @vue/cli-plugin-pwa not creating service-worker.js

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps

So i have a pre existing Vue application and want to add PWA. I installed [@vue/cli-plugin-pwa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli-plugin-pwa) and after the first build my registerServiceWorker.js (in src) and manifest.json (in public) was automatically created and seems to be working fine. But from my understanding it should also generate a services-worker.js in my dist folder after i run npm run build. If i upload the build files to a server i am getting

```
A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE
Error during service worker registration: TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
```

This also happens if i create a custom service-worker.js

How I added a custom service-worker.js

1: Created service-worker.js in src folder

```
// service-worker.js
console.log('Service Worker Registered!')
```

2: Created vue.config.js in ~/

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...other vue-cli plugin options...
  pwa: {
    name: 'My App',
    themeColor: '#4DBA87',
    msTileColor: '#000000',
    appleMobileWebAppCapable: 'yes',
    appleMobileWebAppStatusBarStyle: 'black',

    // configure the workbox plugin
    workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',
    workboxOptions: {
      // swSrc is required in InjectManifest mode.
      swSrc: './src/service-worker.js',
      // ...other Workbox options...
    }
  }
}
```

If i run npm build with the custom service-worker.js it still does not create a service-worker.js in my dist folder and get the same errors when uploading to a server. The server is a https enabled server. am i missing something or misunderstanding it? thanks in advance.

Edit: I also get the same error if i manually add a service-worker.js file in my dist folder

registerServiceWorker.js

```
import { register } from 'register-service-worker'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    ready () {
      console.log(
        'App is being served from cache by a service worker.\n' +
      )
    },
    registered () {
      console.log('Service worker has been registered.')
    },
    cached () {
      console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.')
    },
    updatefound () {
      console.log('New content is downloading.')
    },
    updated () {
      console.log('New content is available; please refresh.')
    },
    offline () {
      console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.')
    },
    error (error) {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error)
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had very similar problems many times. Looks like it's something on plugin side especially when you use custom sw name or custom sw at all.

What i can recommend - instead of using a plugin (which is using workbox). use workbox directly. It's a 3command setup.

```
npm install -g workbox-cli
```

Then in your project

```
workbox wizard
```

Answer questions and this will generate a workbox.config.js.

Then just paste the same code you have from plugin for registration and on build process type

```
workbox generateSW workbox-config.js
```

This worked for me. Below is a nice tutorial explaining this process more in-depth

https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/a-5-minute-intro-to-workbox-3-0-156803952b3e

Comment: Hi Filip, Thanks for the response. will give your method a go. it seems like if you install vue with (vue init AppName). cli-plugin-pwa does not work but if you install vue using (vue create AppName) it works fine if you install the app with WPA support or installing it after.

Comment: Did this work for you? I'm literally having the exact same issue and I can't figure this out.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have imported registerServiceWorker.js file in main.js:

```
import "./registerServiceWorker";
```